# Can't change value of boolean variable in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I don't know why the value of 'add_command' variable in my code always be 'True'.
Please help me. Here is my code:

```
df3 = xls.parse(1)

# Function finding will return 4 arrays
Spec3, Grade3, other_scrap3, months3 = finding(df3)

# if Spec3[4] == df1.loc[1, 'Spec'] and Grade3[4] == df1.loc[1, 'Material']:
#     print('Equal')

add_command = False                  # Variable to confirm need to add row for df1 or not
# Looping all row of data frame df1 then find out whether Spec3[i] & Grade3[i] in df1 or not.
for i in range(0, len(Spec3)):
    date, mon = split_month(months3[i])
    for ind, row in df1.iterrows():
        if row['Spec'] == Spec3[i] and row['Material'] == Grade3[i]:
           df1.loc[ind, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
           add_command = False
        else:
           add_command = True
    print(add_command)
    if add_command == True:
       df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
       df2.loc[0, 'Spec'] = Spec3[i]
       df2.loc[0, 'Material'] = Grade3[i]
       df2.loc[0, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
       df1 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)           
       print(df1)
```

Please Note that: with line 3 & line 4 I can print 'Equal', it means add_commande should be change from True to False.
But actulally with line 14: "print(add_command)", I saw that this varialble is always 'True'.
Any help is highly appreciated!

```
**EDIT 1:**  
Here is an example of df1:    
        Spec Material  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  
0        NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     
1  40x25x2.0   SPHT-4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   52  NaN  NaN     
2   42.7x3.5   SPHT-1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8  NaN  NaN     
3   42.7x1.6   SPHT-3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8  NaN  NaN     
4   42.7x2.0   SPHT-4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    4  NaN  NaN     
5   22.2x3.2   SPHT-1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   20  NaN  NaN     
6   48.6x3.5   SPHT-1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8  NaN  NaN     
7   42.0x1.0  HFS436L  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   14  NaN  NaN
```

and here is Spec3 & Grade3 arrays:

```
Spec3:  
['60x47.6x2.0', '60x47.6x2.0', '60.5x2.6', '60.5x2.0', '40x25x2.0', '25.4x3.2']  
Grade3:  
['SPHT2-D15M', 'SPHT-4', 'SPHT-3', 'SPHT-1', 'SPHT-4', 'SPHT2-D15M']
```

**EDIT 2:** 
I just delete `else: add_command = True` and move `add_command = False` to inside `for i in range(0, len(Spec)):` loop then it works.
Can't explain in logic way why it works.
Here is revised code:

```
df3 = xls.parse(1)

# Function finding will return 4 arrays
Spec3, Grade3, other_scrap3, months3 = finding(df3)

# if Spec3[4] == df1.loc[1, 'Spec'] and Grade3[4] == df1.loc[1, 'Material']:
#     print('Equal')

#add_command = False                  **# Delete this line**
# Looping all row of data frame df1 then find out whether Spec3[i] & Grade3[i] in df1 or not.
for i in range(0, len(Spec3)):
    add_command = True                  # Add this line
    date, mon = split_month(months3[i])
    for ind, row in df1.iterrows():
        if row['Spec'] == Spec3[i] and row['Material'] == Grade3[i]:
           df1.loc[ind, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
           add_command = False
        #else:                             **# Delete this line**
           #add_command = True             **# Delete this line**
    print(add_command)
    if add_command == True:
       df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
       df2.loc[0, 'Spec'] = Spec3[i]
       df2.loc[0, 'Material'] = Grade3[i]
       df2.loc[0, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
       df1 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)           
       print(df1)
```

Comment: You should at least an example of your ```df1``` dataframe. As far as it seems your data has all compatible with your if statement which makes your value True.

Comment: check if this statement is correct  `if row['Spec'] == Spec3[i] and row['Material'] == Grade3[i]:`

Comment: @ThunderHorn: I already check this if statement by insert a print('Yep') after this command. It can show 'Yep', but still add_command still True

Comment: @furkanayd: I already added example of df1 as your request in my post. Please check it

Comment: what is the output of `row['Spec']` and `Spec3[i]` and what `type(Spec3[i])` and `type(row['Spec'])` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is your answer

```
for i in range(0, len(Spec3)): #you loop for each index in spec3
    add_command = True                  # Add this line
    date, mon = split_month(months3[i])
    for ind, row in df1.iterrows(): #then you loop through the rows 
        if row['Spec'] == Spec3[i] and row['Material'] == Grade3[i]:
           df1.loc[ind, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
           add_command = False
           # Here it changes to False once it found the condition in the row that is why it is working 
        #else:                             **# Delete this line**
           #add_command = True             **if you have the add_command =True**
           # For each item the add_command will be different it will change all the time
           # so the add command will give the value for the last item all the time

    print(add_command)
    if add_command == True:
       df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
       df2.loc[0, 'Spec'] = Spec3[i]
       df2.loc[0, 'Material'] = Grade3[i]
       df2.loc[0, mon] = other_scrap3[i]
       df1 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)           
       print(df1)
```

Comment: I add a command  if type(row['Spec']) == type(Spec3[i]):  print('IF statement is correct')  and the result is: it print out 'IF statement is correct' 6 times

Comment: One more thing. Please teach me how to take break line and highlight code as your comment. I read help, but when I press Ctr+K, it can not toggle text as code. Many thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I know what I missed. I should stop the loop right after `IF` statement is `True`

Answer (score 0):

The if condition was never true, so the `add_command = False` was never reached. You could print the variables to see the run-time values, for example `print('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(row['Spec'], Spec3[i], row['Material'],Grade3[i])` before the IF statement.

If you know a set of values that should give you the true condition of IF, you can also check them through dataframe operations.

Comment: @Vadim Kotov: Thank you very much!. I try your suggestion  but I don't know how to breake line in comment box to show the result. I can inform that surely IF statement should be correct. Like this (40x25x2.0 40x25x2.0 SPHT-4 SPHT-4)

Comment: @lodolfo: You should stop the loop once the IF condition is true. Otherwise, as long as the last row of df1 does not meet the IF, the ELSE always kicks in and makes the final value of `add_command` `False'. If you could explain a little more of your data and goal, I believe these nested loops could be replaced with a few dataframe operations.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you very much. Now I can explain why when I delete the line `else : add_command = True`, this programe works correctly.